# Markov chain question

Tags: statistics

I'm stuck with this question saying that, we have a homogeneous MC which is indecomposable and aperiodic, if $\tau$ is the random time of return back to any fixed state. Show that there exist $C>0$ and $q<1$ such that $P(\tau>n) \leq Cq^{n}$.
I'm not sure whether the question is missing some information about what's $q$ here.
Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: I guess you should assume that your MC is finite, otherwise $\tau$ can be infinite.

Comment: yes, probably that's one assumption i need. but how do i start to prove that inequality anyway?